# deleting file from sdcard

Tags: android

Why doesn't this code work :S

```
public void delete(String name) {
    File file = new File(
            activity.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
            name);

    if (file.exists()) {
        String[] files = file.list();
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            boolean deleted;
            if (new File(files[i]).isDirectory())
                delete(new File(files[i]).getName());
            else {
                deleted = new File(files[i]).delete();
                Log.d(new File(files[i]).getName(),
                        Boolean.toString(deleted));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And i am using the permission

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

And when i checked the value of deleted i found it false :S

Comment: Try closing the file handles immediately after deletion. Also I think you have to refactor your code to show directories and files clearly, its confusing to me atleast

Comment: what do you mean with your code to show directories and files clearly ?

Comment: Is this  `File file = new File(activity.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
            name);` a directory? It seems like this is a directory from which you are using .list to list out all the files and then delete them one by one. Basically refactor to demonstrate this fact clearly else everything just says file or files.

Comment: And close this new handle after deletion  `deleted = new File(files[i]).delete();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
public static boolean deleteDirectory(String name) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
File path= new File(
            activity.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
            name);

            if( path.exists() ) {
                File[] files = path.listFiles();
                for(int i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
                    if(files[i].isDirectory()) {
                        deleteDirectory(files[i]);
                    }
                    else {
                        files[i].delete();
                    }
                }
            }
            return(path.delete());
        }
```

Comment: there is not a method called close in File class

Comment: You are right - I am sorry, long day- just try the above code - it works for me

Comment: Also I think the reason why your method doesnt work is because list() returns only filenames and not entire paths. So I think you are deleting at the wrong location. So best to use listFiles() instead which returns file array objects to the files themselves.